# Create content fields order

Tags: nodes, entities

How can i reorder fields in "node/add/"?

the current order:

```
title 
vocabularies 
body
...
```

i would like to have

```
    title 
    body
    vocabularies 

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop the fields in the order you want at page at the "manage fields" or "manage display" pages.

You can reach these pages for eacht content-type via the links beside eacht content type at:

admin/structure/types

Manage fields is used at the node/add or edit screens.
Manage display is used for the actual display, like when a visitors sees the page.

Comment: what version of drupal are you referring to? can't find this on drupal 6

Comment: You are right, this is for drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with custom moduling, you could implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and adjust the `#weight` attribute of each element. The heaviest weight is the last appeared.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if( $form_id == 'your_node_form' ){
        $form['title']['#weight']   = 1;
        $form['body']['#weight']    = 2;
        $form['vocal']['#weight']   = 3;
    }
}
```

It is valid since D6.